# How to set up separate unit test framwork with spring boot and maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, junit

We have a project written by spring boot with maven. We want to do Unit test and code coverage rate check. To keep project code clean, we want separate the unit test code off.

We want to be two differenrt source project. One was project code, other was unit test code. Use jenkins to run unit test and use Jacoco to see code coverage rate.

Here is how we do it but failed:

1. generate origin jar from maven which not package by spring framework.
2. Create new project used Spring boot + TestNg. (name Test_Project)
3. import the origin jar from project into Test_Project.
4. Run it with failed:

> ```
> Field abc in 'com.example.ngtest.TestNGWithSpringApplication' required a bean of type 'com.example.web.controllers.ABController'
> ```
>
> that could not be found

Can you help me for any information ?

Comment: We add the origin jar into Test_Project by two ways: 1. add it into .classpath file for IDE. 2. add into pom.xml with system path relate set.

Comment: I dont understand why your code should become unclean after adding unit tests?

Comment: We want tester stuff to write Unit code for the project and not impact the project code. It will be nice to separate them into different code source.

Comment: @MaidiGu - Unit tests should reside with the code. Not sure why you want to separate them. Even if testers are going to be contributing to the code, why cant they work with the same codebase? I think you might be complicating things by separating the production code and unit test code into two separate projects.

Comment: I agree to keep unit test code be with code.  But we can't in this case. And for this question, it can be transferred into another way:  how to import spring boot mvn project (multi-module) into other spring boot project?  (let spring boot project A can call another spring boot project B's controller and beans)